# How to delete file in SD card?

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard, delete-file

I use this code:

```
String path = "mnt/sdcard/ten-file.mp3";
File file = new File(path);
boolean result = file.delete();
```

But it doesn't delete the file. Any advice?

Comment: So hardcoded. I recommend you to use [Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "ten-file.mp3";  
File soundFile = new File(fileName);
if (soundFile.exists())
{
    boolean result = file.delete(); 
}
```

Manifest permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that the file exists prior to actually deleting the file:

```
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("/sdcard/appname/data.xml");
if(file.exists()) { 
    boolean result = file.delete()
}
```

The issue I think with your original code is that you didn't actually test to make sure the file existed. You just created a file variable then told it delete it. I referred to the following question from an individual who had a similar problem to you:

[Android how to check if file exist and else create one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476635/android-how-to-check-if-file-exist-and-else-create-one)