# using if condition in splash - Android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-file

I'm tried to implement following if condition to skip the downloading process if the file found. But the if condition doesn't seem to be working and without if condition this works fine. can someone please help to solve this. I think, I used the if condition improperly.

```
File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.sample.project/files/images/");
        if(file.getPath().equals(false)){
            String url = "http://www.sample.com/example.zip";
            new DownloadTask().execute( url );
        }
```

Comment: false is a boolean and getPath() returns a String...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Julien is right. Actually you may try using [exists()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) function of `File` class.

```
if (file.exists()){
    //true
}else{
    //false
}
```

There are many similar questions which may help:

- [Test if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786655/test-if-file-exists)
- [Check if a file exists before calling openFileInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867334/check-if-a-file-exists-before-calling-openfileinput)
- [Check if file exists on SD card on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697650/check-if-file-exists-on-sd-card-on-android)
- [Android how to check if file exist and else create one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476635/android-how-to-check-if-file-exist-and-else-create-one)
- [How to check file exist or not and if not create a new file in sdcard in async task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817551/how-to-check-file-exist-or-not-and-if-not-create-a-new-file-in-sdcard-in-async-t)

Hope it helps.